# Creating Oracle DBLink to insert data into a SQLite Database

Tags: oracle, sqlite, dblink

I've been task with figuring out a way to get data from Oracle and store it in a SQLite database. The back story is we currently use SQLite for our local storage on a mobile application and we currently populate that data via a file download, because the data is a large amount it could take up to 5 minutes to populate the database. An easy solution for us would be to build the table on the server and download it via http. The data is currently stored in a Oracle database on the server. My question is is it possible to create a DBLink from Oracle to SQLite to insert the data into the SQLite database on the server? If this is not possible are there any other solutions that would achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: See [SQLite to Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190660/sqlite-to-oracle). But why can't you use ODBC or JDBC?

Comment: Will using ODBC or JDBC allow me to insert data from an Oracle table to a SQLite table serverside?